# Getting less no. of tweets than requested using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I am using twitteR package of r to get the tweets of a user using userTimeline() function and I requested 500 tweets and I am only getting 106 tweets.Can anyone explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: does the person have more than 106 tweets? some more info on what you've tested and your code would help us solve your problem with you.

Comment: yes the person has 118 tweets